# Generic return type from a generic method

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

Consider a generic method definition like this:

```
public static <T> T getParameter(final Context context, final ContextParameter contextParameter, final Class<T> clazz) {
    return (T) context.get(contextParameter.name());
}
```

Works perfectly to get any type of object until you try a generic object like List<String>. The only way I could make it work was like this:

```
 final List<String> fileNames = 
             (List<String>) ContextUtils.getParameter(context,
                             ContextParameter.EOF_FILE_NAMES_TO_ZIP, List.class);
```

But that requires an extra cast, removing the purpose of having the method. Is there a way to be able to provide `List<String>.class` or something similar to the method? (I know that type erasure prevents `List<String>` to exist but maybe there is a way to do it).

*Note: With making it work I mean without having a type safety warning. I'm aware that the code would work as it is but it is not type safe.*

Comment: not a type safe way. But this will work `List<String> parameter1 = getParameter(List.class);`

Comment: Why do you need to cast? I tried it without the cast and all I got was a warning about type safety.

Comment: @AndreiVajnaII I want a type safe way ;-).

Comment: What you're doing doesn't seem any more type safe with the Class to me. In your example you aren't using the Class except to infer the type of the generic method. A cast expression outside the method is exactly the same as what the generics will get compiled to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this in a type safe way without modifying the downstream code (`context.get()`) because the generic type is erased at run time. In fact, currently the `clazz` argument isn't being used at all: you could simply delete that argument and the method would perform identically since the cast to `(T)` is currently a no-op due to erasure. Your current code is *not type safe even for non-genric classes.*

So if you don't care about the safety, and just want to avoid having casts in the client code, you can just delete the last argument, and a suppress warnings once on the method.

If you want type safety, you can use super type tokens to keep the generic type information: Guava's [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) works and is easily available (IMO every Java project should use Guava already).

It will require downstream changes to your code, however - since you need to capture the type information when objects are added and check it when they come out. You didn't share the code for your `Context` class, so it's hard to say if that's possible, but in any case you'd want something like this:

```
static class TypedParam {
    final TypeToken<?> type;
    final Object object;
    private TypedParam(TypeToken<?> type, Object object) {
        this.type = type;
        this.object = object;
    }
}

public static class Context {
    Map<String, TypedParam> params = new HashMap<>();
    TypedParam get(String name) {
        return params.get(name);
    }
}

public static <T> T getParameter(final Context context, final String name, final TypeToken<T> type) {
    TypedParam param = context.get(name);
    if (type.isAssignableFrom(param.type)) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T ret = (T)param.object;
        return ret;
    } else {
        throw new ClassCastException(param.type + " cannot be assigned to " + type);
    }
}
```

Basically you know the generic type of all the objects in your parameter map, and check with a "generic aware cast" at run time. I didn't include `Context.put()` above, but you'd need to capture the type info when the parameter was added.

You still have a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, but here it's provably type-safe since you are maintaining the type information (in the guts of many generic classes you'll find provably safe casts, so they can't always be avoided even in correct code).

Answer (score 1):

As you already said, there is nothing like `List<String>.class`. So if you just want to read parameters without casts you can use something like this:

```
public static <T> T getParameter(final Map<String, Object> context, final String name) {
    return (T) context.get(name);
}
```

I assume the your context returns `Object` as well and you need to suppress type safety checks anyway for that one method.

Comment: There is something like List<String>.class - it is commonly called a "super type token".

Comment: not directly in language. and even if you provide such "data structure", you can't enforce type safety of any `List` instance anyway since information about "type" of the list is erased. so what is the point?

Comment: You have repeated the points mentioned in question. i dont see how this answer helps.

Comment: my signature does not require cast when used, e.g. `List<String> test = getParameter(ctx, "p");` compiles cleanly

Comment: @sodik This even he has mentioned. What he wants is a type safe way for `List<String>`

Comment: @BeeOnRope good hint, found this http://gafter.blogspot.be/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html about it and looks promissing. Will have a look at it when I come home from work.

Comment: @sodik - actually super type tokens *do* allow you to preserve the generic information at runtime, so they are equivalent of Class without erasing the generic arguments. The trick they use is to create an anonymous class for each token, like
 `new TypeToken<List<String>> {}` and then getting the generic type info via reflection (since it is preserved in the .class metadata).

Comment: @Juru - I added a more complete example in my answer, which tracks the type of the parameters store in `Context` using a super type token and checks them on get().

Comment: @BeeOnRope if you store it additionally, then sure. btw. what about use `Class<T>.cast()` to get rid off that suppress warning.

Comment: Yes, that's the equivalent "raw" way to do it, and here you don't need to store anything additionally since you can just use `getClass()` on the returned object to determine its raw type. It wouldn't work safely for generic types, however. `Class<List<String>>.cast( new List<Integer>() );` will succeed, and then blow up with an unexpected `ClassCastException` some time later in client code.

Comment: I meant instead of `T ret = (T)param.object;` to use `T ret = type.getRawType().cast(param.object`. it should be equivalent and without warning.

Comment: It is not equivalent because that code will incorrectly succeed in casting, for example, a `List<String>` to a `List<Integer>`, when that attempt should clearly throw an error. The `getRawType()` throws away the generic information you need to do the cast correctly.

Comment: the same is true for normal `(T)` cast because of the type erasure of java. I just wanted to help to get rid off that `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`